# Getting error in my first flutter app while trying to run

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I just tried to run my first hello world app with flutter. But its showing error when emulator selected and run clicked.

Here is my code:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main()
{
  runApp(

      Center(child:Text("Hello world!", textDirection: TextDirection.ltr) ,)
  );
}
```

and the error i get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
> org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Whats wrong? how do i solve it?

Comment: at first, run 'flutter doctor' in your cmd

Comment: you can follow this also https://medium.com/@mydogtom/tip-how-to-reuse-gradle-daemon-between-android-studio-and-terminal-df5232d63f38

Answer (score 0):

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25539), you just have to add this to your `build.gradle` file:

```
 packagingOptions {
     pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
     pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
     pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
     pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed and tested Your code and I find No issues App works completely fine and no errors at all 
[image: Here is the output]
Code:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(Center(
    child: Text("Hello world!", textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
  ));
}
```

You can try troubleshooting Your sdk/app

> Try running the command flutter clean
>
> flutter doctor

Hope This works, Add Your Logs so that We can look into the issues after running this commands

Comment: thanks but I tried flutter clean command but doesnt still work

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'YOUR_APP_NAME',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child:Text("Hello world!", textDirection: TextDirection.ltr) ,);
  }
}
```